# when and how does Google Anayltics send tracking requests

Tags: google-analytics

I am NOT having problems tracking my page views or events.

I simple do not see any http requests in the NET tab of Chrome Tool or Firebug.

Do they use a different protocal? Is everything just send onunload?

When and where does Google Anayltics send tracking requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their Javascript reads the cookies, then requests a GIF during the request, where they pass the parameters back to their system for tracking. When you look in Firebug, look at either `ALL` or `Images`. You should see a `GIF` that's been transfered from Google Analytics in your history. When they request the `GIF` they're also passing a long string of `GET` vars to the URL. They should also be providing you with a tracking `cookie`. Which is also set with the Javascript.

Here's more about [how Google Analytics works](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview).

> **How the Tracking Code Works**
>
> In general, the Google Analytics Tracking Code (GATC) retrieves web
>   page data as follows:
>
> ```
> 1. A browser requests a web page that contains the tracking code.
> 2. A JavaScript Array named _gaq is created and tracking commands
>    are pushed onto the array.
> 3. A <script> element is created and enabled for asynchronous
>    loading (loading in the background).
> 4. The ga.js tracking code is fetched, with the appropriate
>    protocol automatically detected. Once the code is fetched and loaded, the
>    commands on the _gaq array are executed and the array is transformed
>    into a tracking object. Subsequent tracking calls are made directly to
>    Google Analytics.
> 5. Loads the script element to the DOM.
> 6. After the tracking code collects data,
>    the GIF request is sent to the Analytics
>    database for logging and post-processing.
> ```

Comment: @AbsoluteZERO, the site is entirely AJAX. I never see a blank pixel or ajax request to any Google domain. Is it all sent on unload by chance?

Comment: actually, correction: i see the pixel onLOAD. i'm still not sure about AJAX requestes or whether they require explicit _gaq.push(...) calls??